# How could i get this Multidimensional array to work?

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, element

```
    string shopInventory[4][2] = {
    {"Boots", "70"},
    {"Sword", "150"},
    {"Armor", "250"},
    {"Shield", "450"}
};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        cout << "Multidimensional Array: " << shopInventory[i][NULL] << ": " << shopInventory[NULL][j] << endl;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make a basic shop system but I'm currently stuck on how to output the array with the details separated.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

Boots: 70
Sword: 150
Armor: 250
Shield: 450

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

Multidimensional Array: Boots: Boots
Multidimensional Array: Boots: 70
Multidimensional Array: Sword: Boots
Multidimensional Array: Sword: 70
Multidimensional Array: Armor: Boots
Multidimensional Array: Armor: 70
Multidimensional Array: Shield: Boots
Multidimensional Array: Shield: 70

Also is there a way for me to remove elements from the array based on what the user wants to buy?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you use a null *pointer* constant as index? Are you trying to print e.g. `shopInventory[i][j]`?

Answer (score 1):

You're overcomplicating it. Your loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    std::cout << "Multidimensional Array: " << shopInventory[i][0] << ": " << shopInventory[i][1] << std::endl;
}
```

And don't use `NULL` like that - if you want to put a zero somewhere, use `0`

Answer (score -1):

You can output the array for example the following way

```
std::cout << "Multidimensional Array:" << std::endl;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( shopInventory ) / sizeof( *shopInventory ); i++ ) 
{
    std::cout << shopInventory[i][0] << ": " << shopInventory[i][1] << std::endl;
}
```

Or you can do it the following way

```
std::cout << "Multidimensional Array:" << std::endl;
for ( const auto &item : shopInventory ) 
{
    std::cout << item[0] << ": " << item[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Take into account that instead of the two dimensional-array you could also declare a one-dimensional array of objects of the type `std::pair<std::string, std::string>`. For example

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> shopInventory[] =
{
    { "Boots", "70" },
    { "Sword", "150" },
    { "Armor", "250" },
    { "Shield", "450" }
};

std::cout << "Multidimensional Array:" << std::endl;
for ( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof( shopInventory ) / sizeof( *shopInventory ); i++ )
{
    std::cout << shopInventory[i].first << ": " << shopInventory[i].second << std::endl;
}
```

or

```
std::pair<std::string, std::string> shopInventory[] =
{
    { "Boots", "70" },
    { "Sword", "150" },
    { "Armor", "250" },
    { "Shield", "450" }
};

std::cout << "Multidimensional Array:" << std::endl;
for (const auto &item : shopInventory)
{
    std::cout << item.first << ": " << item.second << std::endl;
}
```

To use the standard class `std::pair` you have to include the header `<utility>`.

For your task if you are going to remove elements from the sequence it is better to use at least the following container instead of the array

```
std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>>
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::array<std::string, 2>> shopInventory =
    {
        { "Boots", "70" },
        { "Sword", "150" },
        { "Armor", "250" },
        { "Shield", "450" }

    };

    for (const auto &item : shopInventory)
    {
        std::cout << item[0] << ": " << item[1] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Boots: 70
Sword: 150
Armor: 250
Shield: 450
```

Depending on operations that you are going to perform with the collection consider using for example associative containers like `std::map`.